# Picasso as backGround Images

Tags: android, picasso, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

So I have a Recycler View with Grid layout Manager (Image at the End) . Each Item has an ImageView, the code that works fine is below:

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(item1.gadget_image).into(vh1.imgView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onError() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    vh1.pgLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            });
```

Where vh1 is the view holder of the RecyclerView.Adapter that holds the widgets. But I needed a gradient above the ImageView (see Image below). The solution came with another Image View that had as src a drawable that was the Gradient . To implement this I had to set translation of the second ImageView (gradient) to 1dp more than the first ImageView, so as to have the gradient above the main Image. This is the code :

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gradient"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/gradient"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgItem"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:translationZ="1dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

gradient :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

  <gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:endColor="#15ffffff"
    android:startColor="#e1181818"
    android:centerColor="#4e232323" />

  <corners android:radius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

But this solution works only for APIs >= Lollipop, for APIs below Lollipop doesn't work. So I thought that it is better to have one ImageView and Picasso should load the images into ImageViewes as a background and having the gradient as src. Code below:

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(item.gadget_image).into(new Target() {

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {

            vh.pgLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //setting background
            vh.imgView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bitmap));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) {

        }

    });
```

and in the XML file :

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/gradient"/>
```

In the last implementation the problem is that it is too slow to load the images and it confuses the Images with the content. For example if someone clicks to the third ImageView might displays content from the second Item.

My question is how can I implement a solution to have Gradient above the Images for All the APIs without using traslation. like this :
[image]Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Lion789 Can you tell which is your problem, because I don't remember my question. Most probably I have solved that problem

Comment: I ended up using a frame layout for the gradient with foreground, was wondering if that was a good enough solution or you found something else

Comment: @Lion789 I used a View with a background with gradient where I had created in drawable